# How to pass Json structure to Webservice using NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I need to pass a JsonObject to a webservice and for now I find out I should use an `NSDictionary`, what I tried is this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"a@aaa.com", @"Email",
                         @"123", @"Phone",
                         @"123", @"Mobile",
                         @"a", @"Name",
                         @"a", @"Surname",
                         @"a", @"AddressType",
                         @"a", @"Address",
                         @"1", @"StreetNumber",
                         @"A", @"InternalStreetNumber",
                         @"3", @"ZIPCode",
                         @"a", @"City",
                         @"a", @"ProvinceCode",
                         nil];



    NSError *error;
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    // Create the NSURLConnection
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

But it doesn't work and the Webservice doesn't return anything, the problem is that my structure should look like this:

```
userData:{
    Email: "a@aaa.com",
    Phone: "123",
    Mobile: "123",
    Name: "name",
    Surname : "surname",
    AddressType: "a",
    Address: "a",
    StreetNumber: "12",
    InternalStreetNumber: "B",
    ZIPCode: "123",
    City: "a",
    ProvinceCode: "a"
}
```

And I can't understand how to recreate a structure like this. Do I need to use NSDictionary? How can I possibly fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:Request_TimeOut_Time];

     [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Set post body
    if (postDict) //you dictionary
        [request setHTTPBody:[[postDict JSONRepresentation] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

To send `NSDictionary` as a json object, you need to create proper structure of dictionary.

First convert into `NSData`. After that convert into `NSString` and post as json object.

In your Example :

Create a dictionary:

`NSDictionary *tmp`;

Then:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

After converting into `NSData`, you need to convert it into `NSString`.

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonDataencoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And this `jsonString` can be send as json object in a webservice.